# Invalid template file magento 2 after upgrade from 2.2.4 to 2.3.5

Tags: magento

Invalid template file: 'Magento_Theme::js/polyfill.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'head.polyfill'

Comment: Did you got the soluton for this? I am also facing same problem after upgrading

Answer (score 0):

js/polyfill.phtml only exist on magento 2.2, search this line in your magento theme and delete it

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="head.polyfill" as="polyfill" template="Magento_Theme::js/polyfill.phtml" before="-"/>
```